# Getting EOF error but running my code in Thonny produces no errors

Tags: python

I'm learning python and one of my labs required me to:

Write a program whose input is a string which contains a character and a phrase, and whose output indicates the number of times the character appears in the phrase. The output should include the input character and use the plural form, n's, if the number of times the characters appears is not exactly 1.

My code ended up being:

```
char = input()
string = input()

count = 0

for i in string:
    if i == char:
        count +=1
        
if count > 1 or count == 0:
    print(f"{count} {char}'s")
else:
    print(f'{count} {char}')
```

Whenever I run the code in Thonny or in the Zybooks development tab it works but when I select the submit option I keep getting and EOF error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    string = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Does anyone know what's causing the error?

I tried using the break command but it didn't help though I think if I used break at the end of my for statement it wouldn't count all the way. Any ideas folks?

Comment: Are you quite sure that the character and the string are appearing on separate lines?  The first read succeeded, but the second one failed.

Comment: Indeed, when I run the program in thonny it prompts the inputs on separate lines.

Comment: Yes, but the fact that you mentioned a "submit" button suggests that you are submitting this to some validator.  It looks like the validator puts both inputs on the same line.

Comment: I looked at it again, you are correct. I am trying to submit it as 2 separate inputs but it only wants in in a single input.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mr. Roberts the number of inputs was the issue. I had to create a single input and pull what I needed from that single line. My code ended up being:

```
string = input()

char = string[0]

phrase = string[1:]

count = 0

for i in phrase:
    
if i == char:
        
count +=1
```

All good now.